# How do i Format a column like this?

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I was wondering is there a way rename a column like this and if so how would you do it?

```
COLUMN (column1 || ' ' || column2) HEADING "new_name" FORMAT a20;

SELECT (column1 || ' ' || column2)
FROM Table_name
```

Comment: I think Im using oracle

Comment: what exactly do you wish to have between those '  '

Comment: a Space between thee two collumns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are doing this in `sqlplus` you need to use a column alias:

```
COLUMN my_col HEADING "new_name" FORMAT a20;

SELECT (column1 || ' ' || column2) as my_col
FROM Table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the use behind this, you could do

```
SELECT column AS column2 FROM wherever
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically I use column alias on select statement level.

```
SELECT substr((column1 || ' ' || column2),1,20) as "new_name" FROM Table_name
```

Comment: If i do it that way can i make the column have less values

Comment: BillyJones could you provide sample of desired output you want to get? I'm not quite sure what do you mean by "the column have less values". Do you want to reduce number of rows in output or length of value in new column has to be reduced to 20 chars?

Comment: i want the output length to be reduced to 20 Char